# OpenPyXL styling Excel cell partial text

Tags: python, openpyxl

Python `openpyxl` styling Excel cell partial text

I have a requirement to bold the cell partial text e.g. `"Roles\n(please specify using drop-down)"`, In this bold "Roles" and italic font `"(please specify using drop-down)"`.